# Creating Connections to ODBC Data Sources using codes in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I am trying to connect using vb.net (Visual studio 2013) to an MS Access Database 2007(.accdb) using codes. But something is wrong in my code and i can't figure it out.

the Database name is "localDatabase.accdb"

I didn't put any password on my database

I'm using a 64bit

Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
Module Module1
Dim conn As New System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection
Public Sub ConnectToOdbc()

    conn.ConnectionString = Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="C:\Users\MyPc\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\database\localDatabase.accdb"

    Try
        conn.Open()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("Failed to connect to data source")
    Finally
        conn.Close()
    End Try

End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: Whats the error you get? I think an ODBC connection string should be in the format Dim Conn As OdbcConnection = New OdbcConnection("DSN=ODBCNAME;UID=USERNAME;PWD=PASSWORD;")

Comment: It says that 'ACE' is not a member of microsoft
and 'Provider' is not declared. I try to declared it but still there has an error.

here is the site where i got it. 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984313(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: If I remember right, I installed something concerning ACE instead of JET provider. let me find it.

Comment: It's bad practice to keep and re-use one connection for the life of your app. In most cases, you should create a new connection object for  each call to the database. Really.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this line:

```
conn.ConnectionString = Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="C:\Users\MyPc\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\database\localDatabase.accdb"
```

to this:

```
conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\MyPc\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\database\localDatabase.accdb"
```

ConnectionString as the name tell is a string, so you need to wrap it with double-quotes to be recognized as string by VB compiler.

**UPDATE :**

Also you need to change the connection object from Odbc to OleDb:

```
Dim conn As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
```

Comment: here is another error when running it.

 conn.open()

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

Comment: possible cause, the path to MS Access database file is incorrect. Try to double check path to your file..

Comment: can you give me a sample

example,

the path of the database is C:\Users\MyPc\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\database,

the database name is localDatabase.accdb,

and using the same provider

Comment: you should use `Application.StartupPath` if you are going to deploy that.

Answer (score 1):

this is just a hypothesis..
I am using ACE 12.0 now on my app, and it works fine. the different thing is the code try to use this..

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
'instead of obdc
con = New OleDbConnection
    con.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = " & Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "YourDatabase.accdb")
'put your .accdb in your app folder
```

maybe the error is it can't find your .accdb file.

Comment: here is another error when running it.

 conn.open()

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified